# Alarm not Cancelling

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I have created a repeat alarm in an activity, and I'm trying to delete this alarm in another activity. It just won't happen.

Creation code in A.activity

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Log.i("location", String.valueOf(id));

    Intent notifyCycle = new Intent(this,NotifyCycleChange.class);
    notifyCycle.setData(Uri.parse("custom://" + id));
    notifyCycle.setAction(String.valueOf(id));
    notifyCycle.putExtra(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_ROWID, id);
    notifyCycle.putExtra(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_TITLE, titleText.getText().toString());
    notifyCycle.putExtra(DatabaseHelper.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION, "       Enter Description");
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(),(int)id, notifyCycle, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);


    am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
            + 60*1000,timestore, pendingIntent);
    Log.i("At here", "successfully");
```

and the Cancel code in B.activity

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent notifyCycle = new Intent(context, NotifyCycleChange.class);
            notifyCycle.setData(Uri.parse("custom://" + id));
            notifyCycle.setAction(String.valueOf(id));
            PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), (int) id, notifyCycle, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);



            Log.i("location", String.valueOf(id));
            // Cancel alarms
            try {
                alarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("TAG", "AlarmManager update was not canceled. " + e.toString());
            }
```

There are no errors and I have checked for matching for id's

Comment: Is `NotifyCycleChange` class broadcast receiver ?. How do you start Activity B?

Comment: @Libin its broadcast Receiver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create an similar `PendingIntent` used when scheduling the `Alarm`  to `cancel the repeat Alarm`

When setting the alarm you have created `PendingIntent` as  `PendingIntent.getBroadcast` but in when cancel its `PendingIntent.getService` . This is wrong

Create a similar intent to cancel the alarm

```
 Intent notifyCycle = new Intent(context, NotifyCycleChange.class);
 PendingIntent pendingUpdateIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), (int) id, notifyCycle, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
```

And then , cancel the alarm

```
 AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
 alarmManager.cancel(pendingUpdateIntent);
```

Comment: Man didnt see that, wasted a couple of hours on this. thanks a lot man, one more thing , when canceling do the context have to be the same??

Answer (score 0):

When you create pending intents starting and canceling alarm, contexts must be the same.
Please consider to create static method to get context so that you can call it from another activity.